# Django - Models Class Shopping Cart Issue

Tags: python, django

Working on a dashboard done in Django.

The Product class has multiple orders and each order can sell more than one product (for example: order 1 can have 2 tacos (product))

Trying to count the top selling by getting the aggregate number of products sold for all orders.  What is the best way to do this?  Create a dictionary?

[Here is a sample of the models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3noj.png)

Answer (score 0):

To count the quantity sold for all products, you could try something like the following

```
from django.db.models import Count
Product.objects.values("name").annotate(total=Count("quantity"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: It looks like it is converting the dictionary into a list.  How do you return it to dictionary state?